# Defining the result of a SQL Statement

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I want to get the date from this SQL statement and use that as an ExpirationDate in asp classic so I can use that date in an if/then (conditional) statement. Lost on how to retrieve that. Appreciate the help.

```
strSQL = "SELECT SUM (Credits)[Amount] from TableName where id = '" &  id & "' and date >= '4/1/2019' and date >= dateadd(day,-360,getdate())"
```

Comment: Your SELECT does not return a date. It returns rows with `SUM(Credits) {Amount]` as the one and only column. It also has a logic error, because you're using `>=` with both conditions instead of `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: @KenWhite It is working for the Amount going back in time starting 4/1/2019 and that amount expires in 360 days. That has been tested and works.  I will look at your comment on logic error, so I appreciate that, but what I want to extract is specifically what that date is.

Comment: Again, your SQL does not ask for the date. It specifically asks for a single column (`SUM(Credits)[Amount]`. If you want something other than that, you need to add it to your SQL, which most likely will also mean adding a GROUP BY as well. I still believe you have a logic error and that it does not return the rows you want, but if you're satisfied with the results you're getting that's fine. It does NOT do what you claim it does, however.

Comment: @KenWhite There's no doubt that you know this better than I do and I agree that it is not asking for a date.  It is asking for an Amount.  But that Amount will expire in 360 days.  So if you signup today for an amount, that Amount is good for those 360 days - then that Amount doesn't exist and you would have to signup again, etc.  So the question is, how would I capture that end date and use it as an expiration date.  That is what I am struggling with.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Then as I said in the first place, your logic is wrong. If the expiration date is 360 days from the start of the period, then you're either looking for dates between the start and expiration, or dates that are equal to the start date + 360 days.. There's no way that `>=` and `>=` meet your stated requirements. And if you want the expiration date back, then you need to add that to the list of columns in your SELECT statement. If there are going to be multiple (different) expiration dates returned, you'll also need to add a GROUP BY expiration date to the query.

Comment: Your best bet is to [edit] your post and start over. Post sample data, the results you'd like to get out of that data, and your effort to obtain those results, and ask your question based on that information.

Comment: @KenWhite Appreciate your comments and I will need to work at that in understanding what you are asking for because the statement as written gives me the amount for that stated period of time - I just don't have the expertise to go a lot further with that.  But again, I will review and try to edit it if I can get there.

Comment: I'll try again. If the start date is today (4/19/2019), then 360 days from now would be around 4/14/2020. Right? So your current WHERE clause says *list all dates that are greater than today and also greater than 4/14/2020*, which means that you're actually only looking for days greater than or equal to 4/14/2020. (The only dates that satisy both criteria required by AND are those greater than the latter date.) So either you're looking for dates greater than or equal to the expiration date, or you're looking for rows that  expire within the next 360 days, in which case the two `>=` are wrong.

Comment: @KenWhite My first Date of 4/1/2019 - prevents the Sum(credits) from counting amounts paid previous to that date.  The second Date counts all days in that 360 days and then after that would require another purchase to qualify. I just used my localhost and manipulated the table and it tested out fine. So what I was looking for is that last date (361) to use as an expiration date before another purchase was necessary.  So I could response.write the expiration in the user's account. The code seems to work and perhaps there is a better way to write the sql. I do appreciate your help though.

Answer (score -1):

You can add another SQL query with `dateadd(day,-360,getdate())` and get the expiration date. However, as you are getting the date based on your current date you can get it using ASP instead of SQL (i.e. `DateAdd("d",1,Now())`) assuming your ASP server and SQL server are in the same time zone.

Comment: SQL and ASP server are same time, so not an issue.  Expiration date must be related to SUM (Credits)[Amount]

Comment: Not sure I understand. What is the data type of credits? Assuming it's numeric (as you are getting the sum), SUM (Credits) will also return you a numeric value and not a date value.